# 500 when clicking on "post" sort option in reputation tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

Visiting this URL currently gives me a 500:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-07-30%2000:45:30Z

Trying to sort by "post" in my [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes?tab=reputation) also doesn't work (which is how I discovered this in the first place).

Comment: Oh, an error page. Disappointing. I thought you meant you got 500 rep...

Comment: How did you get that `StartDate` parameter on the URL? Clicking around shouldn't do - removing it shows everything as normal.

Comment: @Oded The `href` of the "post" sort/subtab has `StartDate` in it.

Comment: I  must be stupid, 'cause I can't see that. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: @Oded screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPF4.png   Of course, it's working now, but the link I posted ^  still gives a server error.